Why switch flashes when I turn it off
When I turn off electric switch for my water heater ( 3 phase domestic electric connection ) ,it flashes ..as if there’s arc or short circuit
Switch off

Switch on

Please see the flash appears when the switch is being turned off
Check out the video here
Please this is not happening always
What is this issue ?
Please note that tripper for this particular room trips once in a while ..could this be a reason ?

Does "tripper" mean circuit breaker or something else? As far as the flash/arc, that can be quite normal - key question is whether this is a new problem or it has always been this way.

Yes it means circuit breaker.

Yes, The circuit breaker trips once in a while for this room ever since i moved in.. i started noticing if anything is wrong then i found this flash recenty

Switch arcing is normal. An electric water heater typically draws a lot of current and this will cause arcing more frequently and with a bigger arc (that is easier to see and hear).
Hard to tell if the arcing you are experiencing is normal or not, though. You could open up the switch and see if there are any scorch marks that would indicate an abnormal amount of arcing (as switches should be able to handle normal arcing without ill effects).
The breaker tripping might or might not be related. Does the tripping breaker also control the water heater? They typically get a dedicated breaker in more modern panels, but if your house is old it might be shared with other circuits.

The tripper controls water heater & other electrical fixtures in the room.May be I should get a dedicated Circuit breaker for the water heater
